# Python Asyncio file.write after request.get(file) not working

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm using Asyncio and aiohttp to asynchronously get files from an endpoint. My status codes for the request are successful but when I try to write the files everything is always empty for some reason.

This is what my code looks like right now:

```py
async def download_link(url:str,my_session:ClientSession, filename:Path):
    async with my_session.get(url, allow_redirects=True) as response:
        with filename.open(mode='wb') as f: #Line 3
            await f.write(response.content)

async def download_all(urls:list, filenames:list):
    my_conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=10)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=my_conn) as session:
        tasks = []
        for item in zip(urls,file_names):
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(download_link(url=item[0],my_session=session, filename=item[1]))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks,return_exceptions=True)
```

I've also tried to put `async` in front of the with on line 3, inside the download_link function. And I've also tried making the code that opens the file and writes into it a separate async function a such:

```py
async def store_response(response, filename:Path):
    async with filename.open(model='wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

I know the files I'm fetching from do have data, when I use multi-threading I'm able to get data back. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You should not use `async with` with the result of `open` function. Neither call `await f.write(...)` with the result of `open` becasue this method isn't a coroutine. Check the  library [`aiofile`](https://pypi.org/project/aiofile/) to make this operations on files fully async.

Comment: If you don't want to install an extra library, you can use the method `run_in_executor` of the event loop.

Comment: Hmm, can you please provide an example, I looked at the aiofile library and just tried this `async def download_link(url:str,my_session:ClientSession, filename:str):
    file = fp.joinpath(filename)
    async with my_session.get(url, headers = headers, allow_redirects=True) as response:
        async with async_open(file, mode='wb') as f:
            await f.write(response.content)`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting basically I changed `with filename.open` to `async with async_open`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this code to download files asynchronously with no problem and good speed.

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import aiofile

async def download_file(url: str):
    filename = url.split('?')[0].split('/')[-1]

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            if not resp.ok:
                print(f"Invalid status code: {resp.status}")
            else:
                try:
                    async with aiofile.async_open(filename, "wb+") as afp:
                        async for chunk in resp.content.iter_chunked(1024 * 512):   # 500 KB
                            await afp.write(chunk)
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    print(f"A timeout ocurred while downloading '{filename}'")

asyncio.run(download_file("https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png"))
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask about the `async for chunk ... ` line, does that speed it up for you?

Comment: When you are downloading a file, it can be of several GB of size, this means that fully downloaded probably it is not a good idea to put it in momery for then write it to disk. So, a good aproach is instead of get the full file, iterate over the content, get a chunk of the data every time and write it to disk. The `for` has `async` in front because `iter_chunked(...)` is an asynchronous generator . Check the documentation for [Asynchronous Iteration Support of aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/streams.html#asynchronous-iteration-support).

Comment: So I think it doesn't speed up your download speed at least directly, just handle bigger files with no problem. If you want you can tune the parameter of `iter_chunked` and use chunks of biger size, it may improve the download speed. Test diferent sizes and use the size with better result.